# Unable to install angular fire @angular/fire@latest

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angularfire2, angularfire

I just started freshly a new angular material project. And it fails with below errors

```
moblizeit@Vikrams-MBP scanbuddyadmin % ng add @angular/fire@latest
ℹ Using package manager: npm
⚠ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.

The package @angular/fire@latest will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: scanbuddyadmin@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!   @angular/fire@"7.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/moblizeit/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/moblizeit/.npm/_logs/2023-05-21T03_28_48_338Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

The package.json looks like the below

```
{
  "name": "scanbuddyadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^0.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `package.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "@angular/fire": {
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3348#issuecomment-1536262612

Also it seems that this will be fixed with Angular Fire 7.6.0

Answer (score 1):

the `@angular/fire@"7.5.0"` wants a angular version of 12-15 but you angular version is 16. but you can add it with `--legacy-peer-deps`.